# How to remove engine cooling fan from a W169 Mercedes A-Class

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz, fan

How do you remove engine cooling fan from A-Class Mercedes W169?

Comment: I love the straightforwardness and simplicity of this question, awesome :)

Comment: This should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAk1iD13iBg

Comment: There is an umpteem number of achieving that. Nevertheless, if you want to use the fan and/or the engine we could use more details.

Comment: How does the cowling and engine cooling fan come out of the dngine compartment

Comment: Looking at it i think i might need explosives to get it out it seems  very tight many thanks to anyone  that can help

Answer (score 0):

unplug the fan connector and make sure every thing is cold 
then twist the fan clockwise 
it should be lose from its main frame of the radiator 
then try easily to get it out without touching the oil tubes of the 
AC as force can damage the tube and it will cost you
he patient as its too narrow hood and you will find it difficult to remove it if you have big hands

another solution for big hands get under the hood and remove the protective plate do the same and you have to get it from the hood not from down